# Best way to implement custom search form

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-forms, drupal-search

Firstly, I am a Drupal newbie and am still alien to many of Drupal's core concepts. My questions probably seem lame but .... I am trying my best.

I want to implement a custom search form like in the picture attached.

[image]

Hotel, flight, etc. are taxonomy terms.

Depending on the taxonomy term selected, the parameters below will also change, like in the picture below:

[image]

I came across Drupal Search API. I saw the Munich DrupalCon screencast on search api.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rArRwp_1h8Q

From what I have seen so far, I am not sure whether this can be implemented using Search API.

I know this can be implemted using Forms API (I will create the form manually).

I want to know which way will be faster, Forms API or Search API.

I am using : Drupal 7.26

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way is to build a regular [view](http://drupal.org/project/views) with exposed filters.

To add and configure a views exposed filter:

- Go to your views edit page.
- Create the filter criteria that we want our users to be able to control, by clicking the "Add" button, in the filter criteria box.
- Choose the fields that you want your users to be able to filter through them and click "Add".
- In `Configure filter criterion`, check the option `Expose this filter to visitors, to allow them to change it`.
- Configure the rest of the settings to your liking and click "Next".
- After saving the view, this filter should be exposed to your users and they are able to search your view.

For a demo with screenshots; Check this [tutorial](http://bryanbraun.com/2013/08/06/drupal-tutorials-exposed-filters-with-views).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.